# Send data from php to javascript on a different users computer

Tags: php, javascript, session, client, chat

I'm working on a chat client and when one user makes a request to talk to the other user im making a session.  How can the PHP script that makes the session send the session number to the other client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an asynchronous call library like [CometD](http://cometd.org) or any other javascript library for asynchronous communication. Technically, you'll use an [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: there are quite some examples in the [Documentation](http://cometd.org/documentation/2.x/cometd-javascript)